# owl carousel not working after ajax load

Tags: jquery, ajax

i use jquery 1.11 and this code to ajax load wordpress post content in sidebar . everything is good but jquery functions of owl carousel not work and the carousel in post content not showing anything.
ajaxify code to load post content:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
$(".post-link").click(function(){
    var post_link = $(this).attr("href")+' #content';
    $("#single-post-container").html("loading ...");
    $("#single-post-container").load(post_link);
return false;
});

});
```

How can i use .ajaxcomplete() function to load owl carousel after ajax load post.
best regards.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot use this by default is because of no conflict.

From the Codex:

> The jQuery library included with WordPress is set to the `noConflict()` mode (see `wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js`). This is to prevent compatibility problems with other JavaScript libraries that WordPress can link.
>
> In the `noConflict()` mode, the global `$` shortcut for jQuery is not available, so you can still use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    ...
});
```

[Read More in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)